# How to read the txt files I have written in Greek?

Tags: locale

I have some txt files containing greek characters, how can I read them @Ubuntu?

When I am opening one of the files I am getting these "Äåõôåñåýùí".

Here [is a text file](https://rapidshare.com/files/2705744824/badchars.zip) zipped and uploaded at rapidshare.

Comment: Can you upload at least a piece of the file somewhere, gzipped to not modify content, so we can try to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When opening with gedit, you can chose the encoding. Your file might be in `iso-8859-7` (greek) or `windows-1253` encoding. Maybe one of it will work.

If you get the chance in windows: while saving the file select `utf-8` encoding. This is universal and should be readable on all platforms in all countries.

Comment: When I am trying to open the file with windows-1253 encoding I get this:
Could not open the file /home/chris/Desktop/badchars using the Greek (WINDOWS-1253) character encoding.
And when I'm trying to open it with iso-8859-7 encoding I am getting these characters: "Γ±Γ―Γ³Γ―Γ¬Γ―ΓΓΉΓ³Γ§ Γ―Γ"

Comment: You should try with other editors. Maybe there is some problem with the one you are trying to use and the desirable encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add that an easy way to see your files containing Greek and were saved by your friends in their Windows machines is to convert them to UTF-8 with the command:

```
iconv -f Windows-1253 -t utf-8 input.txt > output.txt
```

This will read `input.txt` as Windows-1253 and will write it into `output.txt` as UTF-8.

`output.txt` will contain the correct UTF-8 representation and you will be able to open the file in e.g. Leafpad without further problems.